# Wifi getting connected but not optaining IP address

Tags: wifi, wireless

I am trying to connect to a wifi network which is secured by WEP encryption. The wifi is getting connected but the ip address is not obtaining.

My `/etc/network/interfaces` file content:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wireless-essid Research Lab
wireless-key s:6A844C3AE2
iface default inet dhcp
```

The result of `iwconfig wlan0` command:

```
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bg ESSID:"Research Lab" Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed Frequency:2.44 GHz Access Point: 00:3A:9A:00:2E:90
      Bit Rate:54 Mb/s Sensitivity:0/0
      Retry:off RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality 96/100 Signal level=64/100 Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:0 Missed beacon:0
```

The result of `ifconfig wlan0` command:

```
wlan0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 74:da:38:la:el:85
         UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
         RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
         TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
         collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
         RX bytes:0 (0.0B) TX bytes:4440 (4.3 KiB)
```

Clearly one can see that the wifi is getting connected but the inet address is not obtaining. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Why do you think it is getting connected?  What device is meant to be acting as the DHCP server?  Perhaps it will show an error in its logs.  I don't use WEP, is the s:<xxx> for the key some special WEP syntax?

Comment: @joan my WEP key is like `6A844C3AE2` With this key I am able to connect to the wifi network in my windows laptop. So I have entered the line like `wireless-key s:6A844C3AE2`. I am sure it is connecting to the wifi network because `iwconfig wlan0` displays the correct wifi ESSID which I want to connect. But the problem is it is not acquiring IP address.

Comment: If it was connected you would have an IP address.  You don't have an IP address so you are not connected.  Check the logs.  Are you sure that s: is meant to be there?